# how and where to insert a callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

In my web app, on one of the forms, I have a button(s) that users can click to look up names from the corporate directory.  Once they have found the name, they click on the results and the name and other directory data is populated onto the form. At least, that is how I would like it to work.

My question is how to properly use a callback function so that my data from the look up is brought back to the form where I can parse it out to the correct fields.

From the form page I have the following click function:

```
$(".lookupNameBTN").button({
icons: {primary:"ui-icon-gear"}}) //button
.on("click",function(event){
var btn = $(this).attr("data");

mainApp.lookup(function(obj){
if(btn == "request"){
$("input[name=requestName]").val(obj.cil);
}; //request
if(btn == "client"){
    $("input[name=clientName]").val(obj.cil);
}; //client 
}); //lookup
}); //click
```

The mainApp.lookup() opens the dialog box and loads the server files.

```
mainApp.lookup = function(callback){

    if($("#lookupDialog").length == 0){
        $("body").append("<div id=\"lookupDialog\" class=\"dialogDivs\" />");
    }; //div exists

$("#lookupDialog").load("/RAMP/cfm/common/lookup.cfm",function(r,s,x){
    if(s == "success"){
        mainApp.lookupDialog = $("#lookupDialog").dialog({
            title: "Corporate Directory",
            modal: true,
            width:600,
            height:450,
            position: {my:"center center", at:"center center", of: "#app"},
            close: function(){
                $("#lookupDialog").dialog("destroy").remove();
            } //close
        }); //dialog    

    }else{ alert("Error in Loading"); 
    } //success

}); //load

}; //mainApp.lookup
```

Finally, on the lookup popup, I have the following when the user clicks on the table row with the results:

```
$("#lookupResultsTbl tr").on("click",function(){
var rslt= $(this).attr("data");

// magic goes here to return value

}); //click
```

Once I have the value, I'm unclear how to get it back to the callback function?

I really appreciate the assistance.

Thanks,
Gary

UPDATE:  I added the Coldfusion tag because using CF9 for my server side.  Since this isn't specific to server side, I'll remove that tag.

My question is around continuation.  One the form page, I am calling mainApp.lookup.  I would like to provide a callback in that function that returns the data from the directory lookup.

The load function completes and returns the html for the dialog box.  The user must interact with that dialog by searching for a name and getting the returned results.

I am looking for a way to return the data in the tr click event in the dialog box back to the mainApp.lookup function and then to the callback in the original statement in my form.

Comment: Which callback function? `$("#lookupDialog").load`?

Comment: What's this got to do with ColdFusion?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to safely invoke your callback function in the `if(s == "success")` code block;

```
mainApp.lookup = function(callback){

    if($("#lookupDialog").length == 0){
        $("body").append("<div id=\"lookupDialog\" class=\"dialogDivs\" />");
    }; //div exists

$("#lookupDialog").load("/RAMP/cfm/common/lookup.cfm",function(r,s,x){
    if(s == "success"){
        callback() // here

        mainApp.lookupDialog = $("#lookupDialog").dialog({
            title: "Corporate Directory",
            modal: true,
            width:600,
            height:450,
            position: {my:"center center", at:"center center", of: "#app"},
            close: function(){
                $("#lookupDialog").dialog("destroy").remove();
            } //close
        }); //dialog    

    }else{ alert("Error in Loading"); 
    } //success

}); //load

}; //mainApp.lookup
```

.. which is itself in the standard jQuery .load() callback function anyway .. so I hope I've understood your question properly!